# Nginx Server stops automatically and my site goes down and i need to restart in a period of time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger, digital-ocean

I have set up Nginx server on the digital ocean for my site, but Nginx stops automatically after 10-15 days and my site goes down and I need to restart it every time.

Can anybody tell me that why it is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: If you could post the error from `/var/log/nginx/error.log` at the time your server goes down it would be a lot easier to help you with this issue. Otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: I am facing the same issue actually and in error log file, I cant see anything specific that is making server down

Comment: we need errorlog to find the reason :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the nginx error log usually located at `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Also check that your server isn't being rebooted (due to system updates) and if this is the case ensure that Nginx is in the boot-up process:

```
chkconfig nginx on
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I am enable to find root issue causing nginx to be inactive.
But I have found one solution to prevent downtime.

We can automatically restart nginx on failure

**Check status:**

```
systemctl status nginx
```

**Navigate to nginx.service.d:**

with

```
cd /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
```

Or create with

```
mkdir  /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
```

**Create restart.conf file**

```
nano restart.conf
```

In that file add this content:

```
[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=20
```

`RestartSec=20` is optional it sets the delay to restart after failure.
If you skip this line nginx will be restarted instantly on failure.
For test you can set this delay.

**Reload daemon:**

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Test:

```
pkill -f nginx
sudo systemctl status nginx
```

If you check status after killing nginx, It will be back online after give delay.